# android google calendar api not working when in release

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar api to get events from a public calendar. 
In the google developer console I have created a service account key (json) which I use to setup the GoogleCredential in the android code as follows:

```
 AssetManager am = getAssets();
 InputStream inputStream = am.open("key-file-name.json");

 GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(inputStream);

credential =credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"));
```

**Then I use this GoogleCredential to get the calendar object**

```
Calendar client = new Calendar.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                   new JacksonFactory(),
                   credential).setApplicationName("someAppName").build();
```

**Then I get the next 5 events from this calendar**

```
  com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events nextEvent =
                           client.events().list("public-calendar-id@group.calendar.google.com")
                                   .setTimeMin(new DateTime(new java.util.Date(), java.util.TimeZone.getDefault()))
                                   .setMaxResults(5)
                                   .setOrderBy("startTime")
                                   .setSingleEvents(true)
                                   .setShowDeleted(false)
                                   .execute();
```

While this code works fine in debug when running in android studio, when I build for release (sign with keystore file) it does not work. It just returns the following exception:

> com.google.a.a.c.b.c: 404 Not Found  3097-3187/com.news.apoelnews
>   W/System.err: Not Found  3097-3187/com.news.apoelnews W/System.err:
>   at com.google.a.a.c.d.a.c.b(Unknown Source)

Please help!

**UPDATE**
I have added the use of android API key in the code as follows:

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events nextEvent =
client.events().list("public-calendar-id@group.calendar.google.com")
.setTimeMin(new DateTime(new java.util.Date(), java.util.TimeZone.getDefault()))
.setMaxResults(5)
.setOrderBy("startTime")
.setSingleEvents(true)
.setShowDeleted(false)
.setKey("api-key-string_from_developer_console"))
.execute();
```

This causes the following exception:

> W/System.err:
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
>   Forbidden W/System.err:   "code" : 403, W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
>   W/System.err:     "domain" : "usageLimits", W/System.err:
>   "message" : "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured
>   on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions

PLease note that the API keys are created using the debug and the release SHA-1.

Comment: Since you're using Service Accounts, are you using Calendar for Work ( Google Apps for Work)?

Comment: Why use Service Accounts? From what I know, you can use Service Accounts if you're using Google Apps for Work ([domain-wide authority delegation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/domain#accessing_domain_calendars_as_an_app)).

Comment: You are right. I modified my code now and I only use the android API key.

Comment: add your domain name at developer console

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem was during the build in release the gradle option 'minifyenable true' was messing with the google api class names. So the solution is to include:
 -keep class com.google.api.** { *; } 
in the proguard

Answer (score 0):

Has the api/Key generated for the Signed Keystore, and have u changed the api key in ur project which matches your release Keystore

Comment: I have created an API key with the debug and release SHA-1. But as you can see in the code I only use the json file generated when creating the service account key. Where should I use the API key? And if the API key is needed then why does it work in debug? Thank you

Comment: The Json u r using is of Degug Keystore, Download the Json for the Release Keystore and replace it in your assets folder

Comment: When I create the service account key that generates the json file, I do not specify SHA-1 which identifies debug or release. Where can I download the json for release keystore? The API keys generated with release SHA-1 do not produce a json file

Comment: Are you creating the key for Web or android

Comment: I do not use the API key. I use the json file from the service account key. If i use the API key in the call I get the following: "code" : 403,
 W/System.err:   "errors" : [ {
 W/System.err:     "domain" : "usageLimits",
W/System.err:     "message" : "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",

Comment: to generatethe json file u followed some steps right using KeyStore..., The Json File that was u r using is off the Degub Keystore.

Answer (score 0):

i am not much aware about Google Calendar Api but 
Have tried to generate SHA-1 key with your release key-store?  if you want to  generate release apk then you have to create new key for Google Calendar and release again it will work for you.

follow this some useful links : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#releasemode

https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores

try it